# boost.python expose function that returns vector<MyClass>

Tags: c++, python, boost, vector, shared-ptr

I'm writing an extension module for Python in C++ and I am using boost.python. I want to expose a function that returns a `vector<MyClass>`. I'm not exactly sure how to do this and how it will interact with Python WRT memory management.

My first thought was to wrap `MyClass` in `shared_ptr`, thus the function would return `vector<shared_ptr<MyClass>>`. Would this help? What happens when `shared_ptr<MyClass>` instances get to Python land? Will they ever be freed?

So my question is: how can I expose a function that returns a `vector` of `MyClass` instances to Python without leaking memory?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `vector<MyClass>` those instances in the `vector` are obviously (kind of, since the vector internally uses dynamically allocated memory) stack allocated. It would be different to `vector<MyClass*>` which is essentially a vector of dynamically allocated `MyClass` instances. In this case, a `vector<shared_ptr<MyClass> >` is the better solution.

Boost Python and smart pointers work well together, which can be seen in [this](http://wiki.python.org/moin/boost.python/PointersAndSmartPointers) example.

To expose `vector`s or `list`s use the indexing interface, which can be viewed [here.](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/python/doc/v2/indexing.html)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Boost.Python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/python/doc/index.html)'s [indexing suite](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/python/doc/v2/indexing.html).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into more-less the same problem: I had to have a module written in C++ returning a vector of custom objects.

While (as mentioned above) [Boost.Python indexing suite](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/python/doc/v2/indexing.html) worked fine and made me like Boost.Python even more, I ended up refactoring the stuff, so that was returning a boost::python::list of my objects instead. This made the invocation code in Python cleaner.

With regards to freeing the memory, besides the indexing suite, also have a look at [manage_new_object](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/python/doc/v2/manage_new_object.html#examples) return value policy:

> ... wrap C++ functions which return a pointer to an object allocated with a new-expression, and expect the caller to take responsibility for deleting that object...

I use this and it works fairly well.