# How to expose a function which returns a variant vector?

Tags: python, c++, boost, vector, boost-python

I'm looking for a tiny working example of a `C++` module which has a method that returns a `variant` `vector` and exposes it to `Python` (it seems like an ancient problem, which dates back to [2004](http://webmail.dev411.com/t/python/cplusplus-sig/043x8dxgxm/c-sig-boost-variant-in-python-interface), but I could not find any clear answers onwards). I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7268496/boost-python-expose-function-that-returns-vectormyclass) and [this](http://blind.guru/boost_python-and-boost_variant.html) and much more, but still I can not find a solution. As for [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/python/doc/v2/indexing.html) it seems to throw to its reader tons of information right away. What I want is a tiny working example with one tiny method which returns one tiny vector. This is what I have now:

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost:python

typedef boost::variant<int> variant;
typedef vector<variant> vector;

class Some{
   private:
      int idx;
   public:
      Some(...){ ... } //not important
      vector MyMethod(){
          return vector{1};
      }
 };

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(some){
    class_<vector>("vector").def(vector_indexing_suite<vector, true>());
    class_<Some>("Some",
        init ... //not important
        .def("MyMethod",&Some::MyMethod);
}
```

I have no problems with compilation, linkage and usage of the resulting shared library, if I comment out this method. However, if there is such a method returning a vector, then I get a whole stack of errors. I guess, I need to make some extra steps, like playing drums and doing some other magic stuff (or some data types conversion etc), but I do not know exactly what steps.

Comment: I don't know whether that makes a difference, but the documentation you linked belongs to an old version of boost. There is a link at the top that takes you to the newest version.

Comment: you may give us the error you get!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should write `to_python_converter` for `variant`, something like this should work:

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <boost/python/suite/indexing/vector_indexing_suite.hpp>
#include <Python.h>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>

typedef boost::variant<int> number;
typedef std::vector<number> vector;

vector function()
{
   return vector{1};
}

struct number_to_object : boost::static_visitor<PyObject*>
{
   static result_type convert(number const& v)
   {
      return apply_visitor(number_to_object(), v);
   }

   template<typename T>
   result_type operator () (T const& v) const
   {
      return boost::python::incref(boost::python::object(v).ptr());
   }
};

void init_module() {}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(pyexc_test)
{
   using namespace boost::python;

   class_<vector>("vector").def(vector_indexing_suite<vector, true>());

   to_python_converter<number, number_to_object>();
   implicitly_convertible<int, number>();

   def("function", function);
   def("init_module", init_module);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I will check it now and report back.